# Exception Birt : IrunAndRender

Tags: java, postgresql, birt

I got this error when running task Birt (IrunAndRender.run)

NB: The value '2783072953' for a table is OID in PostgreSQL

The following items have errors:

```
    `ReportDesign (id = 1):
    - Cannot get the native data type name for column: 1
    Cannot get the column type name.
    SQL error #1: Mauvaise valeur pour le type int : 2783072953
    Cannot get the native data type name for column: 1
    Cannot get the column type name.
    SQL error #1: Mauvaise valeur pour le type int : 2783072953
     ( 1 time(s) )
    detail : org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.api.AdapterException: Cannot get the native data type name for column: 1
    Cannot get the column type name.
    SQL error #1: Mauvaise valeur pour le type int : 2783072953

     at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:435)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:149)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:115)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:178)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1678)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:82)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:61)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:45)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:42)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:45)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:33)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layoutChildren(HTMLPageLM.java:126)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:84)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:90)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:148)
     at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:71)
     at urssaf.cfe.stats.BirtStats.runBirt(BirtStats.java:61)
     at urssaf.cfe.stats.etats.EvtAnalyse.genererRapportSuivant(EvtAnalyse.java:97)
     at urssaf.cfe.stats.AffichageStatsHtml.Traitement(AffichageStatsHtml.java:51)
     at urssaf.cfe.stats.AffichageStats.doService(AffichageStats.java:76)
     at urssaf.cfe.Service.doService(Service.java:321)
     at urssaf.cfe.Service.doPost(Service.java:340)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
     at ...
  `
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the data type for the column to something that supports the value you are receiving, such as bigint. The Postgresql website states:

> integer   4 bytes typical choice for integer  -2147483648 to +214748364
>   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html

The number you are receiving is too big for the integer data type.